# Independent numpy random numbers using GNU parallel processes

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, random-seed, gnu-parallel

As far as I understand, it is recommended to use numpy.random.SeedSequence() when running parallel processes with random number generators that are independent of each other. This seems to be easy when using the python multiprocessing library. However, I couldn't come up with a way to use this functionality with GNU parallel. Is there a neat way to ensure independent random number generation running python scripts using GNU parallel?

Comment: Do you understand the underlying problem? I.e. using the start time as a seed instead, which was the traditional default?

Comment: @MSalters Well, I think that using the system time while several processes are started would result in using the same seed, which in turn would result in the same pseudo-random numbers for those processes. However, my understanding of generating random numbers is limited. Initially, I thought simply passing the process ID to the python script as an argument would solve the issue but then the seeds are linearly dependent, so currently, I am thinking of using a list of truly random numbers from something like random.org I'd appreciate any other ideas?

Comment: Your clarification makes sense; I think the question is now answerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea in the comment about using a process ID is indeed a valid idea. The problem is that you want enough entropy in your seed - the output of a **Pseudo**-Random Number Generator is solely defined by its seed. Using the start time as a seed will give different output over time, but often the same output for parallel jobs.

Using *only* the process ID is also not a good idea, because it's typically a fairly small number. There's often only 16 or 32 bits of data in there. Combining it with the time adds entropy.

Now you mention that the process ID's might be "linearly dependent" - it is common enough on Linux to have incrementing process ID's. This in itself is not a real problem. Any decent PRNG should have be strong enough to handle such seeds.

One notable exception is cryptography. In that case, the independence of the various PRNG's might be a much bigger concern, but we'd need more details to be sure. That's why the common advice is to use existing crypto libraries.

Comment: Just a suggestion, or rather a question about whether or not it could be useful, but what about using a hash function over the process ID and use the result as the seed for the PRNG ?

Comment: @Jenny: That can help to fix a PRNG with a bad seeding implementation. But typically, a good PRNG (such as the Mersenne Twister) already has a state that's much larger than the seed itself, so it already has a seeding process. A hash function typically reduces the number of bits, instead of increasing it, and a hash function certainly cannot produce two outputs for a single input.